# Need to automatically insert a future date into HTML email template

Tags: php

I have an automatically generated order confirmation email on my e-commerce site.  I would like to ad a line to it that tells my customers when they can expect to receive their order.

Since I only do fulfillment one day a week (Wednesday) and use 1 day shipping, my customers will always receive their shipment on the Thursday following their order.  Unless they place their order on Wednesday in which case it will get bumped to the next week.

I need some code that will that will look at the date of the order and if its not a Wednesday determine the date of the next Thursday.  If it is a Wednesday then the it needs to skip the following Thursday and determine the date of the next week's Thursday.

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know — we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>

<?php
```

Comment: `strtotime("next wednesday +1 day")`

Comment: Please show us that you've done some research and effort into solving your problem...

Answer (score 1):

The following will calculate from today's date.

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("next wednesday +1 day"));
print_r($date);
```

Output

```
27-06-2019
```

Or if you need from specific date

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("next wednesday +1 day"), strtotime("24-06-2019"));
print_r($date);
```

Output

```
27-06-2019
```